# Counter in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to implement a counter in my spring boot application, which is accessed by thousands of users and i need to increment the counter by 1, when a user hits a particular endpoint.

An object gets this value as id and is saved in a NoSQL ( cosmos ) database.

What could be the most efficient implementation ?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I would add an intercepter to the endpoint that increments a field in a datastore

Comment: Is it thread safe though ? There could be simultaneous request coming in given the volume of transactions in my case.

Comment: Use AtomicInteger class, this has all. supported method you mentioned above.

Comment: So long as the interceptor doesnt have state it would be thread safe as it is updating a row in a database, so it will be making use of the databases transaction security safe guards.  Updating a counter is a "cross cutting concern" which might be needed in several places, so using an intercept decouples things nicely.  If you have an event driven architecture then the interceptor can add a message to a queue in which case you are decoupling the processing of the increment event from the sender.

Comment: You might also want to checkout the Spring Boot Actuators; this is a sub project that can provide a number of interesting things like health status and metrics (including custom metrics) again depends on your use case of course

Comment: I like the idea of interceptors and will definitely look into it. I was also thinking of another approach on similar lines - use a @PostConstruct, get all records from DB in a list, get the size, and store it in an AtomicInteger in the service layer and keep incrementing it on every new request. How does that sound ?